# "mount if not exists" clause in docker-compose and ansible

Tags: docker, logging, ansible

I define several path where I should find logs in a ansible dictionnary:

```
"/data/athena/jenkins_master/home/logs"
"/data/athena/jenkins_master/home/logs/*"
"/data/athena/jenkins_master/home/logs/*/*"
"/data/athena/jenkins_master/home/jobs/*/builds/*"
```

Then, in docker-compose, I want to mount all relative volumes, but as I have recursive info in path, I decide to mount parent directory.

docker-compose.yml

```
{% for log in in_filebeat_dict.filebeat.logs | default([]) %}
      - {{ log.path.split('*')[0] }}:{{ log.path.split('*')[0] }}:ro
{% endfor %}
```

Now my problem is that for all those entries, it will try to mount several time: `"/data/athena/jenkins_master/home/logs"` and will fail

As I use it in another part (filebeat), I must keep the detail in the dictionnary.

I wonder how should I include a "mount if not exists" clause in  docker-compose

How should I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply check uniqueness before looping:

```
{% for log_path in in_filebeat_dict.filebeat.logs | default([]) | map(attribute='path') | map('regex_search','^([^*]+$|.*?(?=/[*]))') | list | unique %}
      - {{ log_path }}:{{ log_path }}:ro
{% endfor %}
```

Regular expression `^([^*]+$|.*?(?=/[*]))` is to select paths without `*` or first part of path with `/*`.